# Fortran77 User Input Validation

Tags: validation, input, fortran, runtime-error, fortran77

I need the user to enter only real numbers when prompted. An error message should be displayed and program should stop in case the user enters a character or any other symbol. How can i do this in fortran 77.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed, you probably want to have more tries, because what you have in your question does the compiler does automatically.

You can use the `IOSTAT=` or `ERR=` specifiers.

```
   INTEGER IE
   DO I = 1, MAX
     READ(*,*,IOSTAT=IE) X
     IF (IE.eq.0) GOTO 10
     PRINT *,"Wrong input, try again."
   END DO
10 CONTINUE
```

or

```
   GOTO 10
20 PRINT *,"Wrong input, try again."
10 READ(*,*,ERR=20) X
```

Comment: Don't use list directed input if you care about errors.  There's no obligation on compilers to report "bad" input via iostat either.  The only robust and portable way is to roll that validation yourself.

Comment: I cannot agree. From a single record it is quite OK.

Comment: Type a slash as input.  See what happens.

Comment: OTOH it enables one to read arrays from both comma and space sepparated lines and other stuff. In practice it works.

Comment: I dont want to read comma and space seperated lines. How can i work that out?

Comment: Did you try to apply any of the answers here?

Answer (score 0):

improving  the user interface a little, i like to  read a string, then do the error check on an internal read:

```
    character insting*80
    ie=1
    do while(ie.ne.0)
    read(*,'(a)')instring
    if(instring(1:1).eq.'q')stop
    read(instring,*,iostat=ie)x
    if(ie.ne.0)then
        write(*,*)'invalid input ',trim(instring),' is not a real number'
    endif
    enddo
```

(note `trim` is not f77 btw, but its easy enough to replicate if needed)

Note, with some effort you can handle the pathalogic cases. A leading '/' or ',' throws no error but leaves the value of x unchanged (likely system/compiler dependent however!), so you can do something like this:

```
     x=-999999.   
     read(instring,*,iostat=ie)x
     if(ie.eq.0.and.x.eq.-999999.)then
            .. code to handle error..
     endif
```

You could alternately use `index` to look for the bad characters. On my system a decimal  `.` by itself is taken as zero. That gets a bit cumbersome to handle, but it can be done by parsing `instring`

Comment: Try your program with the input `,ListDirectedInputCanBeEvil`, which is not normally regarded as a valid real literal.

Comment: @IanH What format do you suggest that gracefully handles the case where the user keys in an integer?

Comment: Any numeric edit descriptor that can be used for real input (F,E,D,G) that has .0 as the decimal part of the descriptor, with the field width specification matching the field width of the input, assuming that interpreting the integer literal as a real is what you mean by "graceful".  But if you actually want to validate that the input text matches some particular "real literal like" pattern then you pretty much have to do that yourself - there's no hard requirement on Fortran processors to detect "bad" input.

Comment: i need to generate an error if the user inputs say 4/3 or 4*3 ...With the integer data type it only takes the first digit and ignores everything after the symbols